# Login loop when adding a custom domain for appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

Chrome, regular App Engine app (not restricted to Google Apps domain).

In application management:

1. Open "Application Settings".
2. Click "Add Domain".
3. Input a domain into "Domain Name" and click "Add Domain".
4. Redirects to page with URL https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=CPanel&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fadmin.google.com%2F###MY_DOMAIN###%2FAddAppEngineService%3FappId%3D###MY_APP_ID###&hl=en
   where ###MY_DOMAIN### and ###MY_APP_ID### are populated correctly.
   There I see my account under "Select and account" which I can click.
5. Click account.
6. It opens the same Account Chooser page with slightly different URL, with *auth* parameter in *continue* url param.
7. Clicking again on my account just changes the *auth*.

That ###MY_DOMAIN### may or may not be registered with Google Apps (tried on third-level domains with different second-level domain part). Account may or may not be owner of Google Apps that are installed on that domain (added different Google accounts to app owners and tried from both).

UPD: there's already issue filed 2 months ago https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9779

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding second-level domain, not third-level. And that second-level domain should be registered with Google Apps. Then, after adding the second-level domain you'll be able to configure which third-level domains maps to which App Engine applications in Apps settings.